# How to subscribe to real-time XMPP RSS feeds with Superfeedr

Tags: python, xml, rss, xmpp, superfeedr

I'm trying to subscribe to feeds with Superfeedr, and I've got a python wrapper for XMPP up and running, and I'm receiving the `dummy.xml` successfully.

I don't quite understand how to add more sources, however?  I've tried adding a few `superfeedr.com/track/`'s, but I get no new feeds from it (though I do seem to get a confirmation of subscription).

I'd like to add as many real-time (non-POLL) feeds as possible, perhaps by using PubSubHub servers.

I'd really appreciate some help towards this - where do I find such feeds? Can I subscribe to the whole superfeedr.com real-time feed just by adding `/track/` ?  Or will that only filter the feeds I'm subscribing to?  Also, as I'm subscribing from my `XMPP.py` client on my Amazon server, what exactly is my Subscriber URL (callback) ?

Where do I go from here?

I'll add more info if needed, just let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Superfeedr is an API which will help you gather data from feeds that you're supposed to curate yourself. So the whole process starts with you collecting a list of feeds to which you want to subscribe.

The [Track API](http://documentation.superfeedr.com/misc.html#track) does not help you find feeds, but rather helps you build *virtual feeds* that match a given criteria. For example, if you want any mention ot 'stackoerflow' in any feed, you could use track for that. Think of it as RSS feeds for search results, but in realtime (forward looking).

Finally, if you use [XMPP](http://documentation.superfeedr.com/subscribers.html#xmpppubsub), you don't need a callback url, as these are part of the [PubSubHubbub API](http://documentation.superfeedr.com/subscribers.html#webhooks).